# Update Sencha Architect project from Sencha Touch 2.2 to 2.3

Tags: sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.2

How can I update Sencha Architect project from Sencha Touch 2.2 to 2.3? 

 I have Architect 3.0 installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this now by right clicking the library in the inspector and choosing from the context menu.  I think there is also an option in the top menu as well.  hint: the library is toward of the bottom in the resources section.

Answer (score 1):

The current beta build doesn't offer this yet.